Make an absolute positioned element overflow dialog content that has overflow-y auto
My goal is to have a dialog that has a header, content and footer where the content has a flexible height and scrolls in case it becomes bigger than x px.
This works great, until I try to add an element that also works with absolute positioned subelements (like a custom dropdown for example).
I build a JSFiddle to showcase the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/a590f24r/
The basic structure looks like
<main>
  <dialog>
    <header>
      Example
    </header>
    <div class="content">
      <form>
        <div class="custom-drop-down-element">
          <input />
          <ul class="dropdown-list">
            <li>Example 1</li>
            <li>Example 2</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <button>
        Close
      </button>
    </footer>
  </dialog>
</main>

With the core css part looking like
.content {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.custom-drop-down-element {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-list {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0; right: 0;
}

I found similar questions that had no answer to this (Allow a drop-down element to overflow a container that has hidden or scrolled overflow & ui-select dropdown in modal with overflow)
The screenshot below shows the unwanted behaviour - the absolute positioned element leads to scroll of the content. Removing overflow-y: auto will ofcourse solve this problem, but lead to issues when I have more content and actually want the dialog to scroll.

Is there a way to define that the absolute positioned element is allowed to overflow the parent container?

To allow .dropdown-list "escape" the container and overflow a scrolling .content its parent .custom-drop-down-element should be static, not relative:
.custom-drop-down-element {
  width: 100%;
  /* position: relative; */
}

Positioning of .dropdown-list will be relative to dialog which has position: fixed.
In the snippet bellow, ul is hidden and becomes visible when the input is focused. Text was added to show that .content can be scrolled. All style changes, except for position of .custom-drop-down-element, are illustrative.


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

dialog {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content {
  max-height: 70px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.custom-drop-down-element {
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-list {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ddf;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  display: none;
}

input:focus~.dropdown-list {
  display: block;
}
<main>
  <dialog>
    <header>
      Example
    </header>
    <div class="content">
      <form>
        <div class="custom-drop-down-element">
          <input />
          <ul class="dropdown-list">
            <li>Example 1</li>
            <li>Example 2</li>
          </ul>
          <br> Text 1
          <br> Text 2
          <br><br> Text 3
          <br><br> Text 4
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <button>
        Close
      </button>
    </footer>
  </dialog>
</main>



Update
To make a .dropdown-list relative to an actual width of the .content a relative inline-block wrapper can be used:


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

dialog {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

dialog>* {
  text-align: left;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  max-height: 70px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.custom-drop-down-element {
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-list {
  /* subtract the paddings of .content */
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  position: absolute;
  background: #ddf;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  display: none;
}

input:focus+.dropdown-list {
  display: block;
}
<main>
  <dialog>
    <header>
      Example
    </header>
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <div class="content">
        <form>
          <div class="custom-drop-down-element">
            <input />
            <ul class="dropdown-list">
              <li>Example 1</li>
              <li>Example 2</li>
            </ul>
            <br> Text 1
            <br> Text 2
            <br><br> Text 3
            <br><br> Text 4
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <button>
        Close
      </button>
    </footer>
  </dialog>
</main>




This looks very promising! I will check it out tomorrow and flag the response as correct if everything works out :)!

I finally had time to check it in detail. It works on a first glance, but it's not really reuseable for me - I've updated my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/st9o67wf/ now that the dialog is the "relative parent" I have no reference to style the width depending on the width of the "content". So if I set width: 100% it will be 100% of the dialog, not of the content / form / custom-drop-down-element.
When considering building a custom component for this, I don't see how I could achieve something reusable here by doing so...

It cannot be relative to the width of form / custom-drop-down-element, otherwise it won't be able to overlap the scrolling div. But it can be relative to the actual width of a .content - I've just added another snippet.

I will flag this answer as correct, as it technically solves my questions. However, I will still have to find a different solution as I plan to build a "dropdown" component that should also work in any dialog or non dialog scenario....

Thank you! Perhaps, it won't be an easy one and would require a few solutions combined.
